# Databricks : Equivalent code for SQL query

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm looking for the equivalent databricks code for the query.
I added some sample code and the expected as well, but in particular I'm looking for the equivalent code in Databricks for the **query**. For the moment I'm stuck on the CROSS APPLY STRING SPLIT part.

**Sample SQL data:**

```sql
    CREATE TABLE FactTurnover
    (
    ID INT,
    SalesPriceExcl NUMERIC (9,4),
  Discount VARCHAR(100)
  )
 INSERT INTO FactTurnover
 VALUES 
   (1, 100, '10'),
   (2, 39.5877, '58, 12'),
   (3, 100, '50, 10, 15'),
   (4, 100, 'B')
```

**Query:**

```sql
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
     SELECT Id, SalesPriceExcl, 
         CASE WHEN value = 'B' THEN 0
         ELSE CAST(value as int) END AS Discount
     From FactTurnover
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Discount, ',')
     )
     SELECT Id,  
       Min(SalesPriceExcl) AS SalesPriceExcludingDiscount,
       EXP(SUM(LOG((100 - Discount) / 100.0))) As TotalDiscount,
       Cast(EXP(SUM(LOG((100 - Discount) / 100.0))) * 
            MIN(SalesPriceExcl) As Numeric(9,2))
        PriceAfterDiscount
     FROM CTE
     GROUP BY ID
```

**Expected Results:**

```
| Id | SalesPriceExcludingDiscount |       TotalDiscount | PriceAfterDiscount |

|----|-----------------------------|---------------------|--------------------|

|  1 |                         100 |                 0.9 |                 90 |

|  2 |                     39.5877 | 0.36960000000000004 |              14.63 |

|  3 |                         100 | 0.38250000000000006 |              38.25 |

|  4 |                         100 |                   1 |                100 |
```

Comment: What's the issue? Databricks supports SQL, right?

Comment: yes but not every command is recognized if you use it in Databricks.
When you start the command with %sql, it does not recognize all of the functions. Cross apply is one of them.

Comment: @kjmerf I think only [Spark SQL](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/index.html), so you can't copy paste other sql dialects in there

Comment: Yes indeed. That's it. Its the Spark equivalent I'm looking for.

Comment: You'll need to use split and explode.  Something like 
`discounts.withColumn("SalesPriceExcl",explode(split($"SalesPriceExcl",",")))`.
That will give you a row per value in the array, which should basically replace the cross apply

Comment: How many values can be in the discount string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SPLIT` to convert the comma-separated string to an array then use `LATERAL VIEW` and `EXPLODE` to do operations on the elements of that array.  The roughly equivalent syntax (including CTEs) is:

```
%sql
--SELECT * FROM FactTurnover;

WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *
FROM
  (
  SELECT Id, SalesPriceExcl, SPLIT ( Discount, ',' ) AS discountArray
  FROM FactTurnover
  ) x
  LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE ( discountArray ) x AS xdiscount
)
SELECT 
  Id,
  MIN(SalesPriceExcl) AS SalesPriceExcludingDiscount,
  EXP ( SUM( LOG( ( 100 - xdiscount ) / 100.00 ) ) ) AS TotalDiscount
FROM cte
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY Id
```

If you are feeling brave, you could also do this using [higher order functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/16/introducing-new-built-in-functions-and-higher-order-functions-for-complex-data-types-in-apache-spark.html).  I've included two examples below.  I would say these are harder to debug and you should probably try them performance-wise, it depends what you're comfortable with:

```
%sql
-- Convert Discount text column to array with SPLIT function and filter out value 'B' from the array
;WITH filterB AS (
SELECT *, FILTER ( SPLIT ( Discount, ',' ), x -> x != 'B' ) discountArray
FROM FactTurnover
), cte1 AS (
-- Do initial calcs on array
SELECT 
  Id,
  TRANSFORM ( discountArray, discountArray -> LOG( ( 100 - discountArray ) / 100.00 ) ) discountArray2
FROM filterB
)
SELECT
  Id,
  EXP( AGGREGATE ( discountArray2, CAST( 0 AS DOUBLE ), ( x, y ) -> x + y ) ) AS x
FROM cte1;

-- all in one example
SELECT 
    Id,
    EXP( AGGREGATE( TRANSFORM( FILTER ( SPLIT ( Discount, ',' ), x -> x != 'B' ), y -> LOG( ( 100 - y ) / 100.00 ) ), CAST( 0 AS DOUBLE ), ( z, a ) -> z + a ) )
    AS final
FROM FactTurnover
ORDER BY Id
```