# Column wise word count

Tags: sql, scala

I have a table displaying book title (_c1), pages (_c2), etc.
I am interested in finding the most occurring term in the title (most occurring word). I tried the following:

```
val countData = spark.sql("select value as _c1, count(*) from inputpr2q1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(_c1,'_') group by value").show()
```

It is saying from is wrong in this query. I don't know if this function is available in scala. I was wondering how I could fix this or if I could just use scala to find the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is what comes after your CROSS action, it does not work this way in Spark SQL.
The STRING_SPLIT function does not exist, however, there is a similar function named "split" (doc. here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#split)  that allows you to split a column based on a regular expression.
Also, as Spark SQL is based on SQLite, you probably cannot use a CROSS APPLY expression.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994948/databricks-equivalent-code-for-sql-query